# Apple script to merge/move similar folders in a directory into one

Tags: javascript, merge, applescript, directory

I have several folders that have been split into sequences and need to be merged. For example, one sequence of folders looks like "2015A1_lemon_01, 2015A1_lemon_02, 29A1_lemon_03" and another sequence like "Books_01, books_02, books_03".

what I'm hoping is that an applescript (or perhaps even javascript) can be made which takes all the similar folders in the *entire* directory and puts all its contents into one.
The sequence number does not need to be preserved. If the script can just take the contents of every similar folder and put it into a folder like "29A1_lemon" for example, then that would be ideal

The main thing is that all the folder contents get moved to the appropriate folder- the script doesn't have to literally merge everything, although that would be helpful. Also it is critical that the script can look through multiple different folders and not just one sequence at a time.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will examine all files recursively, and for every file that matches the stated regex in the file name, it will move that file to a folder whose name matches the first capture group in parentheses in the regex search.

**Update: I have updated the script to isolate regex matching**.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property foldertoSearch : "Macintosh HD:Users:jweaks:Desktop:test:" --myHome:BigFolder:"
property destinationFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:jweaks:"
property fileRegex : "(.+)_.+" -- checks file name for this pattern, place folder name in a (capture group)

tell application "Finder"
    -- get all files recursively within the search folder
    set oldFileList to (files of entire contents of alias foldertoSearch)
    -- prep the item delimiter to detect potential folder name within file names
    set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_"

    repeat with thisFile in oldFileList
        set n to name of thisFile
        -- files containing a _ will be moved

        set f to my getMatch(n, fileRegex)
        display dialog f
        if f is not "" then
            -- create folder if not already exists
            if not (exists alias (destinationFolder & f & ":")) then make new folder at destinationFolder with properties {name:f}
            -- move the file
            move thisFile to folder (destinationFolder & f & ":")
        end if
    end repeat
    -- restore the old item delimiter
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid
end tell

on getMatch(theString, toMatch)
    -- theString = string to search
    -- toMatch = regex to test if found in the string
    set returnString to "$1" -- $0 whole match, $1 first expression capture group in parentheses, $2 etc.

    set theRegEx to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:toMatch options:0 |error|:(missing value)


    set isMatch to theRegEx's numberOfMatchesInString:theString options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:length of theString} --NSMakeRange(0, [string length])]

    if isMatch > 0 then

        set theResult to theRegEx's stringByReplacingMatchesInString:theString options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:length of theString} withTemplate:returnString

        return theResult as text
    else
        return ""
    end if
end getMatch
```

Comment: Ok, I've updated the script to accommodate using RegEx to match the file and folder names.

Comment: That almost does it but what's wrong with the RegEx in applescript? I tried to change the one you made to the one I had before and it says expected """ but found unknown token...

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is escape characters. You have to escape things like quotation marks " and forward slashes \.  So, if your regex is  .*?_(?=\d+)  then you need to escape the slash with another slash:  .*?_(?=\\d+)

Comment: Edit: It works (accidentally put the export folder in the main folder) but it asks me about each file it wants to move... How can I make it so it only asks about each new set of files instead?

Comment: It works here, so all I know to do is for you to work at getting your regex statement correct, including the ( ) capture group for the folder name. Maybe you need to set up a test folder/files to figure it out? Try not using special codes like \d also.

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment. There is no issues except for the confirmation window pops up for every file which is  not very helpful unless it only asks for each parent folder it wanted to create and move the child files into.

Comment: comment out the line: display dialog f

Comment: Nice work, thank you. I'm glad you added that that feature though because it may be of use however I'm sure of all of my filenames following the same pattern so it wasn't necessary. All files filtered into their proper folders but if they didn't it would just be a matter of making to proper ReGex. Absolutely magnificent tool, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This script will recursively move all files. It puts the burden on you to first provide the list of folder names you're gonna look for in the individual files.

```
property foldertoSearch : "Macintosh HD:Users:myHome:bigFolder:"
property destinationFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:myHome:"
property folderNames : {"29A1_lemon", "Books_"}

tell application "Finder"
    -- create destination folders
    repeat with f in folderNames
        if not (exists alias (destinationFolder & f & ":")) then
            make new folder at destinationFolder with properties {name:f}
        end if
    end repeat

    -- get all files recursively within the search folder
    set oldFileList to (files of entire contents of alias foldertoSearch)
    repeat with thisFile in oldFileList
        set n to name of thisFile
        repeat with f in folderNames
            if f is in n then
                move thisFile to folder (destinationFolder & f & ":")
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have so many folders that it would be very time consuming to enter all of the names. Could it perhaps get the names through ReGex? It would look for .*?_(?=\d+)

Comment: ok, I posted another answer that looks for _ in the filename and moves files to a new dynamically created folder

Comment: The ReGex matching would be much more ideal as I hope to use the script for other directories that don't contain an underscore.

Comment: I altered the other answer to use RegEx to match files. Please see that answer.